# How to catch Json response into my own C# object

Tags: c#, json

What would be the C# object definition for this JSON?

I'm trying to catch this json response into my own C# object.

This is the json response.

```
   {
        "formatting": {
            "b": [
                {
                    "r": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "r": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "r": [
                        {
                            "i": [
                                {
                                    "o": 2,
                                    "l": 172
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

C#
And this is my C# class.

```
  public class formatting
    {
        public List<b> b { get; set; }
    }
    public class b { 
        public List<r> r { get; set; }
    }
    public class r { 
        public List<i> i { get; set; }
    }
    public class i { 
        public List<ol> ol { get; set; }
    }
    public class ol {
        public int o { get; set; }
        public int l { get; set; }
    }
```

and I'm trying to deserialize in this way

```
formatting apiResponseMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<formatting>(responseString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, there will be times where you need to convert your JSON response from APIs to C# classes for serializing, and you can use an online service like https://json2csharp.com/ to reduce toil and get it accurately , remember to never paste anything confidential on an external website.

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class I
    {
        public int o { get; set; }
        public int l { get; set; }
    }

    public class R
    {
        public List<I> i { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public List<R> r { get; set; }
    }

    public class Formatting
    {
        public List<B> b { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Formatting formatting { get; set; }
    }
```